# Paginação blog, limitação de posts

Tags: php, paginação

Tenho um blog incorporado no site e quero limitar o nº de posts por página, mas o problema que me está a dar é que não me limita os posts.

## Código

```
///Ler posts do blog da página atual
$result = mysql_query("$busca LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");
$num_registos = mysql_affected_rows();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_registos; $i++){
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //declarar variaveis
    $id=$linha["id"];  



$busca = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$total_reg = "4"; // número de registos por página
$pagina=$_GET['pagina']; 
if (!$pagina) { 
    $pc = "1";
} else {
    $pc = $pagina; 
}

$inicio = $pc - 1; 
$inicio = $inicio * $total_reg;

$limite = mysql_query("$busca LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");

$todos = mysql_query("$busca"); 

$tr = mysql_num_rows($todos); // verifica o número total de registros 

$tp = $tr / $total_reg; // verifica o número total de páginas 

$anterior = $pc -1;
$proximo = $pc +1; 
if ($pc>1) { 
    echo " <a class='blog-page-link' href='?pagina=$anterior'><i class='fa fa-arrow-    left'></i> Anterior</a> "; 
} 
if ($pc<$tp) { 
    echo " <a class='blog-page-link' href='?pagina=$proximo'>Seguinte <i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i></a>"; 
}
```

Comment: esse código esta a fazer tudo bem, so preciso mesmo de o meter a limitar os posts que nao consigo :c

Comment: Mas o que está acontecendo? Está buscando todos os _posts_, ou nenhum? Ou está dando erro? Explique melhor...

Comment: Dica: podes eliminar o `?>` no final, pois um espaço após ele pode gerar dores de cabeça.

Comment: eu neste momento tenho 4 posts na bd, sim ele vai me buscar os 4, eu no código limitei a 3 e no entanto na 1º pagina aparece me os 4, e se clicar no botao seguinte aparece me os 4 posts na mesma.
O que deiva de acontecer era:
1ºpagina - 3 posts;
2ºpagina - 1post.

Comment: vendo será mais facil:
1º página : http://gyazo.com/04f3929eeedcf38bc5bf248c13830bf5
2º página : http://gyazo.com/99287e8a247e25ded3db17fa2971dc66

Comment: no seu loop é interessante saber se ele esta usando o $limite ou $total

Comment: @cloud tens de por o código que "imprime" os dados no browser.

Comment: Cara eu fiz o teste aqui e deu certo, eu acho que você está fazendo o _loop_ com a variável que trás todos os registros e não com a que trás os limitados. E uma dica, tenta mudar para a biblioteca **mysqli**, pois a **mysql vai ser descontinuada em breve**. Outra dica, tenta usar uma biblioteca para fazer a gestão do DB tipo a [ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi)

Comment: exato foi o que falei ele tem duas variaveis com a query $limite e $total ele deve estar usando o $total

Answer (score 2):

como havia falado você esta montando assim sua query:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from blog ");
```

E deveria ser assim:

```
$result = mysql_query("$busca LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");
```

Comment: agora nao me aparece nenhum post

Comment: vou te aconcelhar a colocar o código completo da pagina .... porem mesmo assim você já sabe que esse query esta sem filtro algum... vai mostrar tudo mesmo... ainda acho que deveria estudar um pouco mais pois a resposta foi dada, você só nao esta sabendo colocar em pratica corretamente

Answer (score 2):

Repare bem na estrutura. No seu código, você não pode usar uma variável antes de ter declarado:

```
///Ler posts do blog da página atual
$result = mysql_query("$busca LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");
```

Como você fez ali no início. As variáveis `$busca, $inicio, $total_reg` ainda não tinham sido declaradas.

Para buscar os registros limitados no seu código e fazer a paginação você precisava do número de registros, o que também não tinha sido feito ainda. Então procure deixar toda a sua lógica de buscas e cálculos primeiro, e por último faça o *loop* para exibição dos registros e links de próxima página e página anterior.

```
$busca = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$total_reg = 4; // número de registos por página


// Verifica se a variável $_GET['pagina'] foi informada na URL, 
// Caso sim, atribui o valor dela, caso contrário atribui 1
$pc = (isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1); 


$inicio = $pc - 1; 
$inicio = $inicio * $total_reg;

$limite = mysql_query("{$busca} LIMIT {$inicio}, {$total_reg}");

$todos = mysql_query($busca); 

$tr = mysql_num_rows($todos); // verifica o número total de registros 

$tp = $tr / $total_reg; // verifica o número total de páginas 

///Ler posts do blog da página atual
$result = mysql_query("{$busca} LIMIT {$inicio}, {$total_reg}");
$num_registos = mysql_affected_rows();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_registos; $i++){
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //declarar variaveis
    $id=$linha["id"];
    /**
     * AQUI VAI O LOOP PARA EXIBIÇÃO DOS POSTS DO BLOG
    **/
}

$anterior = $pc -1;
$proximo = $pc +1; 

if ($pc>1) { 
    echo " <a class='blog-page-link' href='?pagina=$anterior'><i class='fa fa-arrow-left'></i> Anterior</a> "; 
} 
if ($pc<$tp) { 
    echo " <a class='blog-page-link' href='?pagina=$proximo'>Seguinte <i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i></a>"; 
}
```

Procure fazer a validação das variáveis `$_GET` como fiz ali, antes de usa-las, para que não seja gerado um erro.

Sugiro dar uma estudada em lógica e também já ir partindo para Orientação a Objetos. Dê uma passada no blog [Devcia](https://blog.devcia.com), estou publicando uns posts para iniciantes lá.

Comment: Muito bom @Carlos

Comment: Valeu @Otto, quando a gente está iniciando é complicado, eu gostaria que quando eu estava aprendendo, tivesse alguém pra ter me ajudado nessas "bobeirinhas", rsrs.

Comment: só acho que precisa de um pouco mais de esforço ... tipo me ajude e não faça para mim

Comment: É verdade... Se o cara não correr atrás, então não tem futuro em programação. Porque a profissão pode ser resumida em "resolver problemas", rs.

Comment: eu sei, peço desculpa por isso :S vou tentar dar uma olhadela nisso ;) e obrigado aos 2

Comment: De boa @cloud, conseguiu resolver com o modelo que apresentei ali?

Comment: sim deu obrigado :)

Comment: Beleza, então marca como resolvido. ;)

Comment: eu ate marcava mas na vejo aqui nada para marcar  :D